# TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Encountering a pretty frustrating error that pops up whenever one of my api endpoints is accessed. To give context, the application I am working on a **Flask** app using **SQLAlchemy** that stores data in a **PostgreSQL** database set to hold 1000 connections.

One of the ways users can query said data is through the */timeseries* endpoint. The data is returned as json, which is assembled from the ResultProxies returned from querying the database.

The hope was that by using multithreading, I could make the method invoked by the view controller for */timeseries* run faster, as our original setup takes too long to respond to queries which would return large volumes of data.

I've read many other posts with the same problem due to not cleaning up sessions properly, but I feel as though I have that covered. Anything glaringly wrong with the code I've written?

The app is deployed with AWS elastic beanstalk.

```py
@classmethod
def timeseries_all(cls, table_names, agg_unit, start, end, geom=None):
    """
    For each candidate dataset, query the matching timeseries and push datasets with nonempty
    timeseries into a list to convert to JSON and display.

    :param table_names: list of tables to generate timetables for
    :param agg_unit: a unit of time to divide up the data by (day, week, month, year)
    :param start: starting date to limit query
    :param end: ending date to limit query
    :param geom: geometric constraints of the query

    :returns: timeseries list to display
    """

    threads = []
    timeseries_dicts = []

    # set up engine for use with threading
    psql_db = create_engine(DATABASE_CONN, pool_size=10, max_overflow=-1, pool_timeout=100)
    scoped_sessionmaker = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=psql_db, autoflush=True, autocommit=True))

    def fetch_timeseries(t_name):
        _session = scoped_sessionmaker()
        # retrieve MetaTable object to call timeseries from
        table = MetaTable.get_by_dataset_name(t_name)
        # retrieve ResultProxy from executing timeseries selection
        rp = _session.execute(table.timeseries(agg_unit, start, end, geom))

        # empty results will just have a header
        if rp.rowcount > 0:

            timeseries = {
                'dataset_name': t_name,
                'items': [],
                'count': 0
            }

            for row in rp.fetchall():
                timeseries['items'].append({'count': row.count, 'datetime': row.time_bucket.date()})
                timeseries['count'] += row.count

            # load to outer storage
            timeseries_dicts.append(timeseries)

        # clean up session
        rp.close()
        scoped_sessionmaker.remove()

    # create a new thread for every table to query
    for name in table_names:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=fetch_timeseries, args=(name, ))
        threads.append(thread)

    # start all threads
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

    # wait for all threads to finish
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    # release all connections associated with this engine
    psql_db.dispose()

    return timeseries_dicts
```

Comment: Well, is it possible that you're simply trying to query more than 15 (or 10, from your code) tables at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are going about this in a bit of a roundabout way. Here are some suggestions on getting the most out of your postgres connections (I have used this configuration in production).

1. I would be using the [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/) extension to handle the connections to your Postgres instance. If you look at the SQLAlchemy docs you will see that the [author highly recommends](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html) using this to handle the db connection lifecycle as opposed to rolling your own.
2. The more performant way to handle lots of requests is to put your Flask application behind a wsgi server like [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) or [uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). These servers will be able to spawn multiple instances of your application. Then when someone hits your endpoint you will have your connections load balanced between these instances.

   So for example if you had uwsgi setup to run 5 processes you would then be able to handle 50 db connections simultaneously (5 apps x 10 pools each)